# USB mouse doesn't work after I installed Kaspersky

Tags: security

I have a problem with my USB mouse: it doesn't work. This happened after I installed Kaspersky. Do you know any possibility to activate again my mouse? I don't want to reinstall my XP system.

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow - we expect questions to be related to programming. Please try the Super User stack exchange for PC troubleshooting problems.

Comment: "I don't want to install my XP system". So what are you using DOS?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wanted to say "reinstall".I'm using XP system, not DOS.

Comment: Have you restarted the computer? Have you removed the mouse and plugged it back in? Have you verified the mouse still works on another machine? Have you tried uninstalling Kaspersky to see if the mouse functionality returns?

Comment: Are there any conflicts in device manager? Does functionality return in safe mode? Do you have another mouse you can test on this machine? Does this mouse have specialized drivers that you can update?